# AJAX Blocks Image Slider from Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working a menu bar on a webpage. the menubar is based on an image library called [Jcoverflip](https://newsignature.com/jcoverflip)(<=You will find a demo here). The Image Slider works perfectly. That is until I start trying loading in content from different HTML's using AJAX technique.

[image]
When I flip a logo displayed in the top of the above image. Then it indeed does load the content from the other HTML's AJAX style. However the Jcoverflip slider does not work anymore.

Main.html

```html
<div id="mycontainer">
  <div id=w rapper>
    <ul id="flip">
      <li>
        <img href="home" src="Logo.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img href="product" src="Product.png" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

product.html

```
<img id="contact1" src="Contact.png">
```

MainMenu.js

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){

    $("#content").load("home.html");

    $("ul#flip li img").click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#content").load(page + ".html");
        return false;
    });

  });
```

when you click the product logo in the slider then the img of prouct.html will indeed load as intended but the slider does not slide to the product logo. the slider is now frozen.

here is a fiddle for more code. https://jsfiddle.net/qvgadgv4/
the fiddle doesn't work since you need Jcoverflip.

Is there anyone who can help me understand why using AJAX blocks my image slider from working? And come up with a solution to make it work with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i still don't know why this Ajax method blocks my slider from working but I by chance found a solution.

You should ID your img instead of href.

```
<div id="mycontainer">
<div id= wrapper>
<ul id="flip">

  <li><img id="home" src="Logo.png" /></li>
  <li><img id="product" src="Product.png" /></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Then load the content like this instead

```
$("#home, #product, #submit2").click(function(){
         if(this.id == "home"){
             $("#content").load("home.html");
         }

         if(this.id == "product"){
             $("#content").load("product.html");
         }

     });
```

This will load the content into the div of the main html and the slider will work at the same time.